# express-ws: "ws.send is not a function"

Tags: node.js, express, ssl

I'm creating an App using Node.js + Express + Express-ws, but I'm getting the following error when I try to send a message after connection:

```
const fs        = require('fs');
const http      = require('http');
const https     = require('https');
const express   = require('express');
const app       = express();

/*
const key   = fs.readFileSync('./security/server-key.pem', 'utf8');
const cert  = fs.readFileSync('./security/server-crt.pem', 'utf8'); 
const ca    = fs.readFileSync('./security/ca-crt.pem', 'utf8');
const credentials = {key: key, cert: cert, ca: ca};
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
*/

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);

httpServer.listen(8443, function(){
    console.log('Listening on *:8443 \n');
});

httpServer.on('connection', function(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('received: ' + message);
        ws.send(message);
    });
    ws.send('Hi there, I am a WebSocket server');
});

//ROUTES
app.get('/charger/:id', function(req, res){
    res.send('<h1>Hello ' + req.params.id + '</h1>');
});

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.status(404).send('404 — Not Found');
});
```

The commented part is to verify that I can use later HTPPS without changint too much stuff.

The error is the following:

```
TypeError: ws.send is not a function
    at Server.<anonymous> (index.js:26:5)
    at Server.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at TCP.onconnection (net.js:1517:8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, it's because you're not actually using the `express-ws` package anywhere.  Additionally, the `httpServer` object is an instance of the [`http.Server`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener) class, and has no built-in knowledge of websockets.  Even though you call the argument in the callback `ws`, it's not actually a websocket object -- it's an instance of the [`http.ClientRequest`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) class, which has no `send` method, hence the `ws.send is not a function` error.  So, to resolve this, I think you'll need to do something along these lines, per [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws):

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

app.ws('/', function(ws, req) {
  // Now you have a ws object available
})
```

Hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: [Actually](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connection) the argument provided to the callback by the `http.Server.on` method for a `'connection'` event is an instance of `net.Socket`. Nonetheless, the latter has no `send` method either, and indeed the OP doesn't use `express-ws` as they claim. And +1 for the links. ;)